# Android Studio Widget, Text Field, Large, Medium and Small Text is missing all I have is Plain which gives a Name. How can I get it and others?

Tags: android-studio, android-widget

[image]

I'm looking at Youtube examples and I see the instructor has Widgets I don't have, Like different size Text Fields and an analogue clock.

Is there somewhere I can get more Widgets?

Comment: post a link with the video

Comment: I guess this is the Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRXg7RaXG64

Comment: Notice the Widgets the instructor Picks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I obtained a text size same as to the "tutorial" using:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like AndroidStudio has undergone some change. Best option is to enter the "Text" mode and type the style yourself. For ex. if you need an equivalent of LargeText view, then add a TextView and move onto the Text mode and add this line:

android:textAppearance="@style/?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

Or you could also edit the properties of TextView too.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this line `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"` 
inside the TextView after clicking on the Text tab near Design tab located in the middle left to the right of design tab. 
but you have to consider that first of all you need to drag and drop  TextView from Widgets into the user interface or Design section.

Answer (score 0):

Click into the Text tab located middle left to the right of the Design tab, find  the TextView element and within it simply enter this line of code:

style="/?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

Remember this line of code has to be within the  element in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties and then select text appearance and select app.

[image]combat.large

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:text="Large Text"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

Add it inside your Textview tag.